# How to deploy NodeJS App to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I am creating a chat app with NodeJS, and I want to deploy to Heroku. However,  I get an error: `An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.` by using the Github deployment. Does anyone know what is going on?

> Here is some code to see what I have done.

```
    {
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./lib/index.js",
    "test": "jasmine"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "request-promise": "^2.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-sinon": "^0.4.0",
    "jscs": "^2.11.0",
    "proxyquire": "^1.7.4",
    "rewire": "^2.5.1",
    "sinon": "^1.17.3"
  }
}
```

> index.js (Server)

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var routes = require('./routes');
var chats = require('./chat');



app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

routes.load(app);
chats.load(io);


var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server is listening at port:' + port);
```

Comment: Check `heroku logs -t` it'll normally display a bit more information as to why your app is crashing.

Comment: Can I show you my github project, to see if what I have done wrong? I want to do is use the Github deployment in heroku

Comment: Sure, you could also go through this guide as it'll help you integrate GH deployments to Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

Comment: @LeoCorrea I did, but getting the same error.

Comment: What is the error? Link me to your github project and I'll take a look

Comment: the same error shown in the question.

Comment: here is my github: https://github.com/SuzyHakobyan/ChatApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the app working in a Heroku. The issue in your code is that you're not setting the correct port for heroku to work. In the code you provided you're setting the correct port by doing

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

However, in your GitHub project you're hardcoding the port to 3000

```
http.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Instead what you want to do is allow Heroku to define the port or default to 3000 for development like so..

```
var process = require('process');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
http.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server is listening on port: " + port);
});
```

Once you have that, deploy to Heroku and you should see your app running.